# Can we take the square root of both sides of a matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ two square matrices of size $n$ and $\mathbf{A^2=B^2}$.

When can we say that $\mathbf{A=B}$.

Essentially, the question is: When does a matrix have a *unique* square root?

Now, I know that positive (semi) definite matrices have this property, but, can we claim the converse? 
I.e., does a matrix have *unique* square root if *and only if* is psd?

Thank you.

Edit:

Firstly, let my clarify that the matrices are in $\mathbb C^{n\times n}$.

From what I gathered from your replies, there is never uniqueness of the square root except in the case of the all-zero matrix of size $n=1$. 
Moreover, there can be infinite roots even for psd matrices.
From other sources I know that a psd will have only one psd root.

Now let me pose a similar but distinctly different question. Is defectiveness a criterion for existence of root?

Comment: try $n=2$ in full generality

Comment: No.  We may have that matrices $A,B$ such that $A \neq B \neq 0$ but $A^2 = B^2 = 0$

Comment: No. Matricies can have many square roots not just 2.

Comment: Even positive definite matrices don't have unique square roots. Look at $I=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ which is clearly positive definite. Then we have that $I=\left(\pm\begin{pmatrix}\pm 1 & x \\ 0 & \mp 1\end{pmatrix}\right)^2$ for **any** $x$.

Answer (score 2):

A reasonable class of matrices where uniqueness of square root holds, is the class of all hermitian positive semidefinite matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. However, you need to be looking for the square root in this class, otherwise there is no uniqueness. Without positive semidefiniteness, of course, there are $2^n$ square roots of $\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n)$, as long as all $\lambda$'s are nonzero (and there might be infinitely many which are not hermitian, as people demonstrated above).

If you consider the class of all matrices over complex numbers, then I believe that only the zero matrix $1\times 1$ has a unique square root; that is, only one single matrix in one single dimension.

Answer (score 1):

If $A\neq 0$ and $a^2 = 0$, as soon as you are on a field with characteristic $\neq 2$ then
$$
(-a)^2 = A
$$as well. Then, the only matrix that has only one *square root* is $0$; it works only in dimension 1 as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}^2 = 0
$$

---

Note that there are matrices who do not have square roots at all, such as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
$$